# Custom background color in Monaco editor?

Tags: javascript, monaco-editor

Looking through the Monaco examples and typings, it looks like themes can be configured via the `defineTheme` API. I'm trying to apply a VSCode theme to a Monaco instance, and am struggling with how to set the background color (for the whole editor, not just for a token).

Rules are defined as an array of objects with this shape:

```
IThemeRule {
    token: string;
    foreground?: string;
    background?: string;
    fontStyle?: string;
}
```

What should `token` be for setting the editor background?

More generally, is there a good way to apply [this theme](https://github.com/onecrayon/theme-quietlight-vsc) to a Monaco instance, without ripping out theme parsing logic from VSCode source? After a quick attempt to rip out the logic, it seems like a simple custom parser (ie. parse JSON theme definition -> flat list of `IThemeRule`s) is the better way to go.

Answer (score 14):

You can define your own theme and change the `editor.background` in colors option

```
monaco.editor.defineTheme('my-dark', {
        ...,
        colors: {
          "editor.background": '#394555'
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 11):

You can define your theme like this

```
const theme = {
  base: 'vs', 
  inherit: true,
  rules: [
    { token: 'custom-info', foreground: 'a3a7a9', background: 'ffffff' },
    { token: 'custom-error', foreground: 'ee4444' },
    { token: 'custom-notice', foreground: '1055af' },
    { token: 'custom-date', foreground: '20aa20' },
  ]
}
```

and then apply it like this

```
monaco.editor.defineTheme('myTheme', theme)

var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
    value: getCode(),
    language: 'myCustomLanguage',
    theme: 'myTheme'
});
```

Comment: The OP specifically asked for setting the editor background, not each tokens background color. Also token background color seem to have a bug, and currently can't be set in this way.

Zanecat has the correct answer.

Comment: BTW, I just hit a likely bug today where I was forced to set a dummy `colors: {}` even though `rules` was set: https://github.com/cirosantilli/cirosantilli.github.io/issues/82 was failing with `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'editor.foreground')`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Editor, { loader } from '@monaco-editor/react';

loader.init().then((monaco) => {
    monaco.editor.defineTheme('myTheme', {
        base: 'vs',
        inherit: true,
        rules: [],
        colors: {
            'editor.background': '#efefef',
        },
    });
});
```

and then:

```
<Editor theme='myTheme' ... />
```